# Adding a UIImage to UIImageView programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In .h file I declare this;

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
```

In .m file;

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageName:@"http://image.com/image.jpg"];
image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
image.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 50,50);
[self.view addSubView:image];
```

and I connected the UIImageView from the Interface builder. But I need to do this Only by code (without using the Interface Builder). Can someone help me modify the code so that I could do this only by code?

Answer (score 7):

I THINK you have some problem in displaying a remote image in uiimageview  so i thing u should do that fashion.

```
NSData *receivedData = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://image.com/image.jpg"]] retain];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:receivedData] ;

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 50,50);
[self.view addSubView:image];

[image release];
[imageView release];
```

Comment: Why haven't you used `initWithImage` ? and what is the purpose of using the `NSData` as used in your code ?

Comment: Please see third line i have used initWithImage method and as u want to receive an image from a url thats why u have to use dataWithContentsOfURL method to download a particular image in binary format.

Comment: Sorry i am a beginner. Can you tell me the advantage of downloading it in binary form (the way you have coded it) and the way shown in other peoples answers ? (I am a beginner so can you help me undestand)

Comment: Does the other given code(apart from my code) worked for u. if not then i think [UIImage imageName:@"image.png"] worked only for those images which are in Bundle or in project or local but if u want to display an image from web the u have to download synchronously using, dataWithContentOfUrl method.

Answer (score 3):

> and i connected the UIImageView from the Interface builder

That was a mistake. If you do that, the image view pointed to by your `image` instance variable will be the wrong one - the one in the nib. You want it to be the one that you created in code.

So, make no connection from Interface Builder; in fact, delete the image view from Interface Builder so you don't confuse yourself. Make sure your instance variable is also a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView* image;
```

Synthesize the property:

```
@synthesize image;
```

Now your code will work:

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageName:@"http://image.com/image.jpg"];
self.image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
// no memory management needed if you're using ARC
[self.view addSubview:self.image];
```

You will need to play with the frame until the location is correct. Note that the frame will automatically be the same size as the image, by default.

Comment: Does `ARC` comes with iOS 5 ?

Comment: Yes! And see my book to learn what it does for you: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_memory_management

Answer (score 2):

you dont need to connect. This code will work without connecting. Leave IBOutlet out.

Comment: You say that i need to remove `IBOutlet` and remove the `UIImageView` from the Interface Builder and the code will work ?

Comment: yes. you have all that you need: You create an imageView, set an image, set the frame and adding it to a view.

Answer (score 2):

```
UIImage *someImage = [UIImage imageName:@"http://image.com/image.jpg"];
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:someImage];
[self.view addSubView:imageView];
```

Comment: You haven't specified the size of the UIImageView so will the image take the whole frame ?

Comment: it will automatically set it to the size of the image 'someImage' you are initing it with.